# Rails 3.1 collection_select over two levels? (nested models)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am sorry for asking a beginner's question. I can't get a "collection_select" to
work in a specific case.

Im am trying to write a simple Rails 3.1 app based on the following models:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :supply_sites, :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :demand_sites, :dependent => :destroy
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :supply_sites
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :demand_sites
end


class DemandSite < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :site, :class_name => "Site"
   has_many :translinks , :dependent => :destroy
end


class SupplySite < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :site, :class_name => "Site"
   has_many :translinks , :dependent => :destroy
end


class Translink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supply_site, :class_name =>  "SupplySite"
  belongs_to :demand_site, :class_name =>  "DemandSite"
end
```

Migrations are as follows:

```
class CreateSites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :sites do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :codename, :limit => 3

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :sites
  end
end



class CreateSupplySites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :supply_sites do |t|
      t.integer :site_id
      t.float :supply_quantity

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :supply_sites
  end
end


class CreateDemandSites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :demand_sites do |t|
      t.integer :site_id
      t.float :demand_quantity

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :demand_sites
  end
end


class CreateTranslinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :translinks do |t|
      t.integer :supply_site_id
      t.integer :demand_site_id
      t.float :unit_cost
      t.float :quantity

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :translinks
  end
end
```

I want to be able to add a new "translink" (Transportation Link) between a
"Supply Site" and a "Demand Site by selecting from a Drop-Down menu based on
the Codenames of the respective Supply Site or Demand Site, where the codenames
are specfified for the "Sites".

When adding a new "Supply Site" (or a "Demand Site"), the following works well
(from "_form.html.erb" for either Supply Sites or Demand Sites.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :site_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :site_id, Site.find(:all), :id, :codename %>
  </div>
```

Now I want something analogous for for adding a new "Translink" connecting a
Supply Site and a Demand Site. I don't want to add the respective
supply_site_id or demand_site_id manually, but a list of all supply sites to
select one by the codename defined in the underlying site, and the same for the
demand sites. I can do the following to to have a drop-down menu to select, say, one out of the existing supply sites:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :supply_site_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :supply_site_id,  SupplySite.find(:all), :id, :id  %>
</div>
```

However, instead of displaying the id of the supply sites in the drop-down menu, I would rather see and select from the codename of the underlying "site".

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :supply_site_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :supply_site_id,  SupplySite.find(:all), :id ,????? %>
  </div>
```

How can I do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Check the `fields_for` method in the formbuilder api. It allows you to do something like that to work with nested attributes :

```
<%= f.fields_for(options) do |nested_f|
  nested_f.text_field :nested_attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Katen!

The solution turned out to be adding a method to both the demand site class and the supply site class as follows:

```
class SupplySite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site, :class_name => "Site"
  has_many :translinks , :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :translinks


 def supply_site_codename
   self.site.codename
 end
```

end

```
class DemandSite < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :site, :class_name => "Site"
    has_many :translinks , :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :translinks


  def demand_site_codename
     self.site.codename
  end

 end
```

This way I could use the standard "collection_select" and reference the :codename of the underlying "sites" as follows:

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :supply_site_id %>
   <br/>
   <%= f.collection_select :supply_site_id, SupplySite.find(:all), :id,  supply_site_codename %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :demand_site_id %>
   <br/>
    <%= f.collection_select :demand_site_id, DemandSite.find(:all), :id, :demand_site_codename %>
 </div>
```

Now it works as desired. The key was to define a method to reference the corresponding site model.

Stefan